# $POST array not showing anything on echo

Tags: php, forms, post

I have 3 php pages, A, B, C. `$POST` array has all fields in it when i am accessing page A's fields in page B, but when i try to access page A fields in page C it doesnt show anything? but page B's fields do come on page C. A is posting to B, B is posting to C.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please show the offending code. It's hard to identify what is going on here.

Comment: first of all write correct syntax..post data are accessed by super global variable `$_POST` NOT by `$POST`

Comment: To do this,use session start. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_POST` fields are only available on the page that the form is posted to. If you want to pass them on to another page, you'll have to either store them in `$_SESSION` or add them on page B as hidden fields.